# How to list a Parachain on Rococo using CoreTime

Tags: parachain, rococo, coretime

As we know previously, securing a parachain slot was a competitive process through an auction mechanism. With coretime rental, there is no need for slot auctions anymore. Teams can purchase instantaneous coretime or reserve bulk coretime as required. This greatly decreases the barrier-to-entry for software tinkerers and parachain teams.

I want to list my parachain on Rococo. The [official document](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#register-as-a-parathread) still shows old way of registering parathread.

Is there any tutorial/example which shows how to use CoreTime?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer in Polkadot forum [here](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/parachain-consensus-updates-coretime-asynchronous-backing-scalability/4396/8)